# How to construct an Interval in Python in Grasshopper

Tags: python, ironpython, grasshopper

Using [Grasshopper](https://www.grasshopper3d.com/): If I pass a [*domain*](https://rhino.github.io/components/mathematics/constructDomain.html) into a Python component, python sees it as an Interval. I can do operation on it, as below:

```
print x
x.Grow(x[0]-y)
x.Grow(x[1]+y)

print x    
print type(x)
print dir(x)
```

Which prints:

```
20.3596657850938,87.5596657850938
19.3596657850938,88.5596657850938
<type 'Interval'>
['CompareTo', 'EpsilonEquals', 'Equals', 'FromIntersection', 'FromUnion', 'GetHashCode', 'GetObjectData', 'GetType', 'Grow', 'IncludesInterval', 'IncludesParameter', 'IsDecreasing', 'IsIncreasing', 'IsSingleton', 'IsValid', 'Item', 'Length', 'MakeIncreasing', 'Max', 'MemberwiseClone', 'Mid', 'Min', 'NormalizedIntervalAt', 'NormalizedParameterAt', 'ParameterAt', 'ParameterIntervalAt', 'ReferenceEquals', 'Reverse', 'Swap', 'T0', 'T1', 'ToString', 'Unset', '__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__radd__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rsub__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__']
```

However, I can't work out how to construct a new one. They seem very useful, and I'd like to use them more.

I've tried importing the [interval](https://pyinterval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html) module (`Runtime error (ImportException): No module named interval`). I've tried casting a list to an Interval: `Interval([1,2])` → `Runtime error (UnboundNameException): name 'Interval' is not defined`.

I don't know if interval belongs to Python, Iron Python or grasshopper.

How do I make a new Interval?

Answer (score 1):

With some help, I ended up with:

```
print "x is sent in as a domain from the input to this function"
print x, type(x)
print x.GetType().FullName
print x.GetType().Assembly.Location

print "\nThere seem to be two types of intervals, Rhino and grasshopper. Now sure why you'd use a Grasshopper interval, but here it is anyway:"
import Grasshopper as gh
y = gh.Kernel.Types.GH_Interval()
print y, type(y)
print y.GetType().FullName
print y.GetType().Assembly.Location

print "\nTo make a Rhino interval get it from the Rhino.Geometry module"
import Rhino.Geometry.Interval as interval
z = interval(0,1)
print z, type(z)
print z.GetType().FullName
print z.GetType().Assembly.Location

print "\nz is the same as x:", z == x
```

which gives:

```
x is sent in as a domain from the input to this function
0,1 <type 'Interval'>
Rhino.Geometry.Interval
C:\Program Files\Rhinoceros 5 (64-bit)\System\RhinoCommon.dll

There seem to be two types of intervals, Rhino and grasshopper. Now sure why you'd use a Grasshopper interval, but here it is anyway:
0.0 To 0.0 <type 'GH_Interval'>
Grasshopper.Kernel.Types.GH_Interval
C:\Program Files\Common Files\McNeel\Rhinoceros\5.0\Plug-ins\Grasshopper (b45a29b1-4343-4035-989e-044e8580d9cf)\0.9.76.0\Grasshopper.dll

To make a Rhino interval get it from the Rhino.Geometry module
0,1 <type 'Interval'>
Rhino.Geometry.Interval
C:\Program Files\Rhinoceros 5 (64-bit)\System\RhinoCommon.dll

z is the same as x: True
```

If we unpack that: IronPython's `type()` function actually returns a PythonType wrapping the .NET type. `.GetType()` gets the .NET type directly. So `type(x)` gives `<type 'Interval'>` which isn't very helpful, wheras `x.GetType().FullName` gives `Rhino.Geometry.Interval` which tells me exaclty how to get to it.

This is covered in the [Rhino docs here](https://developer.rhino3d.com/api/RhinoCommon/html/T_Rhino_Geometry_Interval.htm), and it has a bunch of useful properties and methods.